# converting immutable fromJS object back to json

Tags: immutable.js

I want to be able to look at my immutable objects for debugging. I find it very difficult to look through an object by clicking on entries and such. Ideally what I would like is the opposite of the formJS function

so,

```
const immutableObj = fromJS({name: 'bob'})
return oppositeJS(immutableObj)  
=> {name: 'bob'}
```

Answer (score 24):

nevermind, I found it in the documentation

```
toJS()
```

Comment: As a side note, I had the same issue debugging Immutable.js data structures and created this little helper for Chrome https://github.com/danielepolencic/immutablejs-devtools

Comment: Btw, their is also `toJSON` in immutable, it's pretty much just an alias but if you wanted to be explicit about the type your expecting (namely JSON) I would use that.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `toJS()`
To read more about https://devdocs.io/immutable/index#map.tojs

```
const immutableObj = fromJS({name: 'bob'})

const backToObj = immutableObj.toJS();
```